# How to make sure everyone has the correct and valid blocky

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency

i'm thinking of programming a cryptocurrency for my computing project and right now I'm researching different methods for validating the blockchain, so far I have found out that bitcoin uses the procceosing power of their miners to make sure someone can't solve more hashes than them but I don't think I will be able to get alot of miners so are there any other methods for this?

Answer (score 0):

BitCoin uses the technique of Proof of work for validating the block. In every block, we have many transactions which are first verified before adding in the block. For the block, verification nodes try to find the proof of work and whoever finds it first will broadcast the block in the network for validation. In Bitcoin, the processing power does matter.

Whereas Ethereum uses Ethash algorithm for the proof of work. Ethash is designed in a way that it overcomes the effect of miners with more processing power. Ethash is memory base algorithm and any general purpose computer can find the proof of work. I think for you it would be best if you dig more into the Ethash.

[Ethash](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a cryptocurrency is a really tough work but on the other side Block-chain in itself is very simple to understand and implement.

You don't need a bunch of miners for a cryptocurrency if you are doing it for a project. A College Project is all about learning and understanding concepts.

Your cryptocurrency is only for demonstration and it does not have any value so you do not need to worry about having bunch of miners.